# REGEX to match 3 or 4 columns of data, one of which might contain spaces

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse, in PHP, a data file describing network nodes. The data file consists of 4 columns, with the 4th column being optional:

```
<Node name>  <Operating System> <Description> <SSL info>
```

e.g.

```
    SIG.SND.SERV                   ZOS        A Big client (MF  LPAR   PROD)
    ADC1                           ZOS        AMEX                           SSL
    ADEPTRA.GB1.PROD               LINUX      BANK OF SOMEWHERE            TLS
    ADEPTRA.GB2.CQA                LINUX      BANK OF SOMEWHERE            TLS
    AIX.EG3C                       UNIX       BARCLAYS                       S+
    AIX.EG3P                       UNIX       BARCLAYS                       S+
    ADEPTRA.GB2.CQA                LINUX      FICO (ADEPTRA) LTD            TLS
    AIX.RMWDEV1                    UNIX       FDCS
    AIX.RMWPROD1                   UNIX       FDCS
    AIX-EFXWRWCK01                 UNIX       EQUIFAX EUROPE
    ANB-DRC-CDFDI                  NT         ARAB NATIONAL BANK (ANB)      SSL
```

My problems lie with column3, the description, which may have spaces and column 4 with may be absent.

I've tried the following REGEXes (with the REGEX checker at https://regex101.com/ :

```
(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S.+?\S)\s+(\S.+)?
```

(This was my attempt to express 'non-whitespace followed by some spaces, non-whitespace followed by some spaces, characters delimited by non-whitespace followed by at least 2 spaces

which works except when the 4th column is absent. My attempts to make the last spaces and characters optional results in columns 3 and 4 matching together:

```
(\S+)\s{2,} (\S+)\s{2,} (\S.+\S)(\s{2,})? ?(\S.+)?
```

I also tried to create a REGEX that specified 'Any characters deliminated by non-whitespace followed by either at least 2 spaces or the end of the string' :

```
(\S.+?\S)[\s{2}|$]
```

which is also 'close but no cigar'.

Sadly yes - that description in the first line does have multiple spaces between the words.

Added a link to one of my attempts: https://regex101.com/r/k9JlZu/1

Comment: Are the columns perhaps separated by tabs? If so, use str_getcsv(). Are the columns always the same width? If so, then just use substr().

Comment: Are the multiple spaces in the description only between parenthesis and are the parenthesis always balanced? If so, maybe `^(\S+)\h{2,}+(\S+)\h{2,}+((?:(?!\h\h|\().|\([^()]*\))*+)(?:\h{2,}([^\s()][^()\r\n]*))?$` https://regex101.com/r/Lo6eo6/1

Comment: Apology time - yes the columns do appear to appear to be in fixed positions so SUBSTR will work. I initially thought a REGEX would be relatively straight-forward (and immune to the columns moving) but having passed the point where substr became a simpler solution, I was too far down the REGEX rabbit hole.  :-)

Comment: I've just found in my input data an example where the description columns may have brackets in it, which complicates things.

Comment: Thanks also to anubhava for indirectly letting me know that the regex101 site allows you to share examples - I didn't know that when I posted the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex to capture 3 or 4 groups in each line:

```bash
^(\S+)\h+(\S+)\h+(\w+(?:\h\w+)*(?:\h*\([^)]+\)(?:\h\w+)?)?)(?:\h{2,}(\S+))?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FYEUdg/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(\S+)`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters in capture group #1
- `\h+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `(\S+)`: Match 1+ non-whitespace characters in capture group #2
- `\h+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `(\w+(?:\h\w+)*(?:\h*\([^)]+\))?)`: Capture group #3 to match spaces separated words *optionally* followed by a `(...)` string
- `(?:\h+(\S+))?`: An optional non-capture group in the end to capture 1+ non-whitespace characters in capture group #4
- `$`: End

Comment: It does work for the example I posted so I've accepted your answer. I've just seen that the description may have brackets in and it doesn't work for those. Also thanks for letting me know that you can save these REGEX tests! I'm probably going to proceed by using substr as what I thought might be an easy REGEX has gotten quite complicated. If you want to come up with one that works with brackets then that would be great, but don't feel obliged.

Comment: You're right - but it doesn't work for this - https://regex101.com/r/FYEUdg/1

Comment: ok so there can be text after `(...)` also in description?

Comment: Yes sorry - I found a couple of examples today that had brackets in the middle of the description i.e. "XXX (XXX) XXX"

Comment: @anubhava - I thought I'd accepted your answer earlier - maybe the 'accept' vote is lost if the answer is edited? But thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/7DcKO))

```
preg_match_all(
    '/^(\S+)\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+(?:\h\S+|\h+\([^)]+\))*)(?:\h+(\S+))?/m',
    $txt,
    $m
);
var_export($m);
```

It only seems that the 3rd group is the tricky one.

I recommend a shorter subpattern than what anubhava is currently showing:

```
(                 # capture group #3
  \S+             # one or more visible characters
  (?:             # a non-capturing group
    \h\S+         # a single horizontal space followed by one or more visible characters
    |             # or
    \h+\([^)]+\)  # one or more horizontal spaces, opening parenthesis, one or more non-closing parentheses, closing parenthesis
  )*              # zero or more times
)
```

The fourth/optional component is caputured inside of a non-capturing group with a zero or one quantifier (`?`).

Pattern comparisons: (anubhava ([423 steps](https://regex101.com/r/td8WQa/1)) vs mickmackua ([396 steps](https://regex101.com/r/o4GD6J/1)))

```
// anubhava
/^(\S+)\h+(\S+)\h+(\w+(?:\h\w+)*(?:\h*\([^)]+\)(?:\h\w+)?)?)(?:\h{2,}(\S+))?$/m

// mickmackusa
/^(\S+)\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+(?:\h\S+|\h+\([^)]+\))*)(?:\h+(\S+))?/m
```

So my pattern is both more concise/D.R.Y. and more efficient in terms of steps.